# Alter where my Jenkins Project build execute shell CWD to a sub-folder of the GIT repository

Tags: node.js, git, shell, jenkins, gruntjs

We have a Jenkins Build server running on Ubuntu 14.04 x64 which is processing three other projects just dandy.  We are integrating a fourth Node.js project but due to fact the outside contractor developing it put all the project files inside a folder of the repository.  So to clarify, the root of the repository is a single folder; in which the *actual* project root is located.

Jenkins checks the repository out but when it runs the NPM commands for install and build fails as its looking for the package.json in the repository root versus the subfolder where all the necessary files are located.

There is lots of information out there on use case which have some similarities as mine, but nothing which provided a solution which worked for me.

I've tried using the full path when executing the shells commands, altering the projects workspace to the subfolder, even researched a way to checkout the specific folder using Git which appears to not be a trivial thing.

I cannot believe there isn't a way to execute a Jenkins build into the checkout repositories  as if a specific subfolder was the root (CWD) for all the scripts being executed in the shell instance.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Can you not just `cd` into that subfolder right before your calls to `npm`?

Comment: lol, I literally *just* found that solution and got it to run successfully when I noticed your comment!  If you post an answer I will gladly accept it.

Comment: Ahh great :) I had a similar oversight sometime ago with a windows batch build. Glad its solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As hinted in the comment, the solution is to `cd` into the subfolder before the calls to `npm`.